# How to get the size of numpy's numeric types in bytes?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the size in bytes of numerical types, in particular those defined by numpy. This is achieved by this helper function,

```
def sizeof(dtype):
    a = np.zeros(1, dtype=dtype)
    return int(a.nbytes)
```

but I was wondering if there would be a built-in, less awkward way of doing it. `sys.getsizeof` is of no help in this case — it returns 400 bytes for all of numpy's numeric types I have tested.

Comment: That's because that's the size of the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`dtype.itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.itemsize.html) or [`ndarray.itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)
>>> arr.dtype.itemsize
4

>>> arr.itemsize
4
```

Comment: Do you know why `arr.dtype.itemsize` works but say `np.float32.itemsize` does not?

Comment: Because it's an instance attribute - not a class attribute. `np.float32().itemsize` works.

Comment: So `np.float32` is an extension of `np.dtype`, not an instance of it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `np.float32` is not a dtype it's [a scalar type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) (that can be used as argument for the `dtype` parameter). `dtype(np.float32)` is the `float32` dtype.

Comment: Interestingly, `dtype(np.float32).itemsize` also works.